# How to apply transform scale inline style in Angular?

Tags: angular, ng-style

How Can I apply transform inline style by passing values from angular

**Here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pros1e)**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>

    <div>Normal</div>
    <div class="scaled">Scaled</div>

    <div
      class="scaledng"
      [style.transform.scale.x]="scaleX"
      [style.transform.scale.y]="scaleY"
    >
      Scaled by Angular
    </div>

    <p>
      How can I scale the last div by passing angular variables
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      div {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: skyblue;
      }

      .scaled {
        transform: scale(0.7, 0.5); /* Equal to scaleX(0.7) scaleY(0.7) */
        background-color: pink;
      }

      .scaledng {
        background-color: pink;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  scaleX = 0.7;
  scaleY = 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

**.ts file**

```
scaleXY = 'scale(' + .7 + ',' + .5 + ')';
```

**template**

```
<div class="scaledng" [style.transform]="scaleXY">Scaled by Angular</div>
```

.7 and .5 would come from your dynamic variables, etc.

[blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emxsxp?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) updated.

And if you don't want it to be so tied up with the scale on both X and Y, you could do it more elegant by sending a full `transform` string, generated by playing with your class properties/inputs/variables as you would need. The HTML would look more like:

```
<div class="scaledng" [style.transform]="transformStyle">Scaled by Angular</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the `ngStyle` directive. I added some input elements for scale values in `AppComponent` and passed them down to `HelloComponent` Where the scale values are used to create the transform style.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acskvs

Comment: I'd also set `changeDetection` to OnPush so that getter won't be called every time Angular runs its change detection inside `HelloComponent`. Otherwise, if you put a log inside the getter, you'd see it's called several times, which can lead to performance issues.